# Using Draft.js with Reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, draftjs

Does anyone have any luck adapting Draft.js for Reagent? There's pretty heavy editing issues if Draft.js is imported right away via `reagent/adapt-react-class`. Cursor jumps, disappearing symbols when you're typing, `onChange` calls with incorrect `EditorState`, you name it.

People are reporting problems like this in clojurians/reagent Slack channel, but it seems there's no solution so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, thanks to [tonsky](https://github.com/tonsky), I got the answer. Reagent/Rum are using deferred rendering with `requestAnimationFrame`, but `Draft.Editor` should be re-rendered immediately when `editorState` is set.

All we need is to call `forceUpdate` for editor parent component whenever editor `onChange` is invoked:

```
:editorState @editor-state-atom
:onChange    (fn [new-state]
               (reset! editor-state-atom new-state)
               (.forceUpdate @wrapper-state))
```

Code example is for Reagent, solution for Rum is identical

Comment: for reagent + reframe: re-frame/sync-dispatch together with reagent/flush will do the trick

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer do we have any code example using reagent and reframe ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea (more of a comment, but I can't provide comments yet), because -- if I remember correctly -- the :content-editable attribute is treated in a special way within Reagent:

Since the problems seem to occur when the Draftjs editor is called from Reagent, would it not help to convert the Reagent-component to a React-component (using reagent/reactify-component), and then use this "reactified" component as a react-component within Reagent, using reagent/create-element? I would assume that Reagent then refrains from meddling with the Draftjs editor.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Nope, that's not working, onChange still returns messed up state. We're about to try tonsky/rum instead of reagent, maybe that will help